# Editing text files while running the program C++

Tags: c++, addition, edit

I really need your help for my C++ homework, Here is what I should do:

1: The user can create a txtfile then input

2:If the user search for that particular txtfile, the program should show the txtfile's contents

3:The user should be able to edit the contents of the txtfile while running the program

I apologize if this had been answered before but I can't find the answer, Please keep the codes as simple as possible as I am still new to programming. I really need your help. Thank you very much.

BTW, I am using Turbo C++ as compiler

Here is my codes:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    char name[20], course[20], age[2], num[15], address[30];
    char gender[1], bday[15], fn[30], focc[20], mn[30], mocc[20];
    char ans, file[30];
    int x;

do{
    ofstream myfile;
    cout<<"File Name: ";
    cin>>file;

    myfile.open(file,ios_base::out);
    cout<<"Student Information \n\n";
    cout<<"Name: ";
    myfile<<"Name: "<<gets(name);
    cout<<"Gender: ";
    myfile<<"\nGender: "<<gets(gender);
    cout<<"Age: ";
    myfile<<"\nAge: "<<gets(age);
    cout<<"Address: ";
    myfile<<"\nAddress: "<<gets(address);
    cout<<"Birthday: ";
    myfile<<"\nBirthday: "<<gets(bday);
    cout<<"Course: ";
    myfile<<"\nCourse: "<<gets(course);
    cout<<"Father's name: ";
    myfile<<"\nFather's Name: "<<gets(fn);
    cout<<"Occupation: ";
    myfile<<"\nOccupation: "<<gets(focc);
    cout<<"Mother's Name: ";
    myfile<<"\nMother's Name: "<<gets(mn);
    cout<<"Occupation: ";
    myfile<<"\nOccupation: "<<gets(mocc);
    myfile.close();
    cout<<"\n\nDo you want to edit? [y/n]";
    ans = getche();

//ansy
if(ans=='y')
{
    clrscr();
    x=1;
}
else if (ans=='n')
{
    x=0;
}
else
{
    cout<<" Invalid choice";
    x=0;
}
}while(x!=0);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? You have only posted your homework requirements, not what your problem is

Comment: im sorry, this is my first time asking here. My question is how do i display the content of the textfile and how do i edit them? thank you

Comment: 1. No, that's not how SO works. 2. Just typing your questions into a search engine (e.g.: "C++ read textfile") yields plenty of samples and tutorials